# Can I reference environment variables in eclipse while defining a (tomcat) server?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, settings

I am using eclipse Galileo. The "New Server Runtime Environment" dialog box contains three fields:

- Name
- Tomcat installation directory
- JRE

I would like to set the tomcat installation directory relative to an environment variable I have set in my OS (win xp).

Can this be possibly done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. I suggest to open a feature request against the Web Tools Project WTP. It should be a simple fix.

Comment: What's even more annoying is when you create a server launch configuration it **hardcodes** absolute path info into VM args ( e.g. -Dcatalina.base="C:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0" -Dcatalina.home="C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.20" ... -Djava.endorsed.dirs="C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.20\endorsed") and even forces the substitute when you use Eclipse variables. What boggles the mind is that they do not touch other command-line properties. Needless to say it is really useless to save this kind of launch configuration with the project

Comment: I agree. My solution is to never deploy unless I have to. I use MockRunner so I can run all my servlets and whatnot in unit tests without the need of an app server.

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak: Filled a bug here : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=416308